# How can I change my front-end setting so that I could unzip it wherever I like?

Tags: php, angularjs

When I zip it directly to my localhost www/ it would be alright but if I put it into a new created folder, it would send a error post:
The requested URL /eolinker_os/server/index.php was not found on this server.

I have tried to auto-fit the path but I failed;
So I have to design the direct path for this application.

```
 function(){return angular.module("eolinker") .constant("serverUrl","/eolinker_os/server/index.php").constant("isDebug",!1).constant("assetUrl","").constant("COOKIE_CONFIG",{path:"/",domain:".eolinker.com"})}(),angular.module("eolinker").run(["$templateCache",function(e){e.put("app/directive/expressionBuilder/index.html","<div class=\"expression-builder-directive\"><div class=\"expression-builder-view\"><ul class=\"first-level-ul header-ul\"><li class=\"first-level-li\"><p class=\"title-p\"><span class=\"iconfont icon-index-magicwand\"></span>
```

I expected the result is wherever I put the application I could always run it on my localhost server without need to put code in specific path.

Comment: Your code seems to have some missing part. Please, complete it.

Comment: I have already edit it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to get your absurl and set it return back to your address location which should help you with this problem.

`var absurl = $location.absUrl();`

`.constant("serverUrl","absurl/eolinker_os/server/index.php")`